# Ambiguous error while executing ksh file

Tags: shell-script, ksh, aix, csh

I have created a audit.ksh file which is used to clear old "*.aud" files. But when i run  this file am getting below error. The strange thing is the commands inside the file works fine while executing openly in prompt.The user is in C shell.

```
TxxxxD01:user 55>./aud_clean.ksh
export RES_RETRY=1: 0402-026 The specified data is not a valid identifier.
TxxxxD01:user 56> echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/csh
TxxxxD01:user 57> cat aud_clean.ksh
cd /oracle/SID/saptrace/audit
find *.aud -mtime +3 -exec rm {} \;
TxxxxD01:user 60> cd /oracle/SID/saptrace/audit
TxxxxD01:user 61> find *.aud -mtime +3 -exec rm {} \;
TxxxxD01:user 62>
```

Comment: You should also look into why your shell initialization files are pulling in /etc/environment; that should be unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *ksh* shell script does not have a sh-bang line indicating that it should be run with ksh, so your csh shell is attempting to run it (with `/bin/sh`, which is the one complaining about the `export RES_RETRY=1` syntax). Add a sh-bang line of

```
#!/bin/ksh
```

to the *top* of the script.

Comment: The `csh` shell executes a shebang-less script using `sh` ([Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/373223)). There may be a shell initialisation file that `sh` executes that has an error, but I don't know what file that would be (`~/.profile` should only be read for login shells), `$ENV` may possibly be defined though.

Comment: Good point; and RES_RETRY appears to be a DNS configuration item, which shouldn't be getting pulled into shell initialization files (and clearly isn't part of the ksh script).

Comment: No, `csh` will execute non-shebanged scripts with `/bin/sh`, not with `csh`. The problem is that the `export VAR=val` syntax is not supported in some ancient shells -- you have to write `VAR=val; export VAR` there. Your solution of adding the `#! /bin/ksh` shebang works, because `ksh` does support that syntax. But the rationale is off.

Comment: Thank you to mosvy and Kusalananda; I've updated the answer to clarify the behavior.